# Biceps growth after biceps curls

Tags: weightlifting

I go to gym 4 times a week. I do various exercise using different machines (chest press, leg press, row etc). On each of these machines I do 3 sets with 10 reps.
I also do 6 sets of bicep curls using 20 pounds dumbbells. I noticed that after using dumbbells my biceps look much bigger but after half an hour or so my biceps go back to same size where they were before the exercise.
My question is.

1. Why do biceps grow so much right after the curls?
2. How can i make my biceps permanently bigger?

Thanks

Comment: I tried yesterday with 25 pounds in each arm and could only complete one set. Should i go back to 20 pounds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your trying to move up in weight, try this.

15 reps at 10 lbs(This is your warm up set to get your form straight and wake up the muscles )

10 reps at 15 lbs (This set adds a little more resistance but still light enough to maintain form)

6 reps at 25 (go all out on this one and see try and maintain form. )

If you did the last set ok, repeat the 6 reps at 25 lbs. The point of these rep ratios is to get your muscles in tune with good form. Once your muscles are warmed up you can start really lifting hard. keep adding to the reps on the last set and soon you'll be doing 25 lbs for ten reps.

Answer (score 4):

1. Because you are using them they become engorged with blood that is being used to provide oxygen to the muscle.
2. Keep doing bicep curls (in various styles) and keep increasing the weight so it is challenging.

Typical weight progression:

- Month 1: 10lbs @ **8** reps x 4 sets
- Month 2: 10lbs @ **12** reps x 4 sets
- Month 3: 10lbs @ **15** reps x 4 sets
- Month 4: **15lbs** @ 8 reps x 4 sets
- Month 5: 15lbs @ **12** reps x 4 sets
- Month 6... carry on

Comment: I been doing it for a month or so and i still cant increase it.  I tried lifting 25 pounds in each arm but i was not able to complete 3 sets

Comment: Vary your weight and rep schemes to progress, I added an example to my question.